# Docker certificate verification issue while installing ODBC driver

Tags: docker, pymssql

```
FROM python:3.9.13-slim-buster  

WORKDIR /home/app
   
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates \
    && apt-get install -y gnupg2 unixodbc-dev g++ curl 

RUN curl -O http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian-rc/jenkins-ci.org.key

RUN curl -k https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -

RUN curl -k https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/11/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

RUN curl -k https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/9/prod/pool/main/m/msodbcsql18/msodbcsql18_18.0.1.1-1_amd64.deb 

RUN apt-get -f install unixodbc

RUN apt-get install ca-certificates

RUN apt-get update && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql18 mssql-tools
```

The above is part of my docker file for the django app. I am getting the following error while creating an image.

```
RUN apt-get update && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql18_18.1.1.1 mssql-tools:
#12 10.74   Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 104.214.230.139 443]
#12 10.75 Reading package lists...
#12 11.42 E: The repository 'https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/11/prod bullseye Release' does not have a Release file.
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql18_18.1.1.1 mssql-tools]: exit code: 100
```

Answer (score 0):

To make this work on your own network, you'll need to add the CA from your local security appliance into your container:

```
sudo cp ca.pem /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/my-ca.crt
sudo update-ca-certificates
```